# VARBINARY and BLOB in mysql for serialized data via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am storing `serialized` data in a mysql and am unsure which field type to choose?

One example of the serialized data output is below,

```
string(393) "a:3:{s:4:"name";s:22:"PACMAN-Appstap.net.rar";s:8:"trackers";a:6:{i:0;s:30:"http://tracker.ccc.de/announce";i:1;s:42:"http://tracker.openbittorrent.com/announce";i:2;s:36:"http://tracker.publicbt.com/announce";i:3;s:23:"udp://tracker.ccc.se:80";i:4;s:35:"udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80";i:5;s:29:"udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80";}s:5:"files";a:1:{s:22:"PACMAN-Appstap.net.rar";i:4147632;}}"
```

The string lengths of the data can vary greatly upto around 20,000 characters.

I understand that I do not want to use `TEXT` data type as this could corrupt data because of character sets that it would have to use.

I am stuck as when it comes to use either `VARBINARY`, `BLOB`, `MEDIUMBLOB` etc.

Let us say if I use `VARBINARY(20000)` does this mean that I can insert a string of `20000` in length safely and if it is over then discard the insert?

Comment: Actually I don't think that it's a good idea to store this kind of serialized data in database. it'd better store in files but if I had to use database, I'd use `blob` (65535 characters).

Comment: This is actually already the solution to the question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with PLB in that you should use `BLOB`. The length attribute specifies how many bytes can be saved in this column. The main difference between `BLOB` and `VARBINARY` is that `VARBINARY` fills up unused space with padding, wheras with `BLOB` only the actual length of the data is reserved for one field.
But as PLB said, only use this if you absolutely must, because it slows down the whole DB in most cases. A better solution would be to store the files in your server's filesystem and save the file's path in the DB.